# Proving of an integral inequality $\int_{-\infty}^{x}(x-z)f_{\alpha_1} (z)dz>\int_{-\infty}^{x}(x-z)f_{\alpha_2} (z)dz$

Tags: integration, density-function

Let us introduce the following notation:
\begin{eqnarray}
f_\alpha (z)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \cos(tz)e^{-|t|^\alpha} \, dt
\end{eqnarray}
with $\alpha \in (1,2]$.

I am trying to prove mathematically my empirical result that if $\alpha_1<\alpha_2$ then

$$\int_{-\infty}^x (x-z)f_{\alpha_1} (z) \, dz>\int_{-\infty}^x (x-z) f_{\alpha_2} (z)  dz, \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}\quad \forall \alpha_1,\alpha_2 \in (1,2].$$

$$$$
$$$$

My ideas and some stylized facts:

1) The integrand is a symmetric function therefore,

$$f_\alpha (z)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \cos(tz)e^{-|t|^\alpha } \, dt = 2\int_0^\infty \cos(tz)e^{-|t|^\alpha} \, dt$$
2) If $z=0$ then
$$f_\alpha (0)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-|t|^\alpha} \, dt$$
This integral cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions except for special cases for $\alpha$ when it is either 1 or 2. How ever it is evident that the smaller the $\alpha$, the larger is the value of $f_\alpha(0)$.

3) Asymptotically $f_\alpha(z)\sim \frac{c_\alpha}{z^{\alpha+1}}$ because for $\alpha\in (0,2]$, $\frac{1}{2\pi}f_\alpha(\cdot)$ is the density function of a stable distribution $S_\alpha(1,0,0)$.

4) If we substitute $f_\alpha (z)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \cos(tz)e^{-|t|^\alpha} \, dt $ into $ \int_{-\infty}^x (x-z)f_\alpha (z) \, dz $, we get
$$\int_{-\infty}^{x}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\cos(tz)\left[ (x-z)e^{-|t|^\alpha}\right] \, dt \, dz$$
by using the symmetry of the integrand, we get

$$2\int_{-\infty}^x\int_0^\infty \cos(tz)\left[ (x-z)e^{-|t|^{\alpha}}\right] \, dt \, dz$$
It is evident that the smaller the $\alpha$ the larger is the expression $\left[ (x-z)e^{-|t|^\alpha}\right]$, but the harmonic function is the biggest obstacle in establishing the inequality.

Comment: It would be great either to prove or disprove it.

Comment: Note that $f_\alpha (z)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}cos(tz)e^{-|t|^\alpha }dt$ is the representation of the density function of a stable distribution in terms of the characteristic function i.e.
$$f(z)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-i t z}\psi(t)dt,$$
where $f$ is the density function and $\psi$ is the characteristic function.

Comment: Note that $f_\alpha (z)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}cos(tz)e^{-|t|^\alpha }dt$ is the representation of the density function of a stable distribution in terms of the characteristic function i.e.
$$f(z)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-i t z}\psi(t)dt,$$
where $f$ is the density function and $\psi$ is the characteristic function.

The stable distribution $S_{\alpha}(1,0,0)$ has the ch.f. $\psi(t)=e^{|t|^{\alpha}}$.

So $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-i t z}e^{|t|^{\alpha}}dt=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\cos(t z)e^{|t|^{\alpha}}dt=f_{\alpha}(z).$$

Comment: There's a type error in my previous message. Correction:
The stable distribution $S_{\alpha}(1,0,0)$ has the ch.f. $\psi(t)=e^{-|t|^{\alpha}}$

Comment: "it is evident that the smaller the $\alpha$, the larger is the value of $f_\alpha(0)$." Obvious, really? Actually, $f_\alpha(0)=2\Gamma(1+1/\alpha)$ hence, indeed, $\alpha\mapsto f_\alpha(0)$ decreases on $(1,2]$ (but not, say, on $(2,3)$...).

Comment: By the way the interval (1,2] is the region of interest.

Comment: "It is evident that the smaller the $\alpha$ the larger is the expression $\left[ (x-z)e^{-|t|^\alpha}\right]$" This is not true.

Comment: "By the way the interval (1,2] is the region of interest." By the way, as should be obvious already from my first comment, I can read. :-)

Comment: $ \frac{1}{2\pi}f_{\alpha}(x) $ is the density function of a stable distribution for only if $\alpha \in (0,2]$ while the integrals in the equalities exists only if $\alpha>1$. Hence we infer that we do not care about anything except except for the interval for $\alpha$ (1,2].

Comment: In the integral $z$ is smaller than $x$. As for $e^{|t|^{\alpha}}$, it is decreasing in alpha if $\alpha>1$.

Comment: No. Let me suggest to plot the graph of the function $\alpha\mapsto\exp(-|t|^\alpha)$ for various values of $t$, say $t=.5$ and $t=3$.

Comment: Re your previous comment: once again **I am well aware that you are only interested in the case $\alpha$ in $(1,2]$** (as already mentioned, I can read). The trouble is that the fact that $\alpha\mapsto f_\alpha(0)$ is decreasing stops to be true soon after $\alpha=2$, hence the "obviousness" of the fact is dubious. (Please stop stonewalling what is said to you if you want this exchange to be the least productive.)

Comment: Rereading your reactions it seems clear that you think that $\alpha\mapsto f_\alpha(0)$ is decreasing because, for every $t$, $\alpha\mapsto\exp(-|t|^\alpha)$ is decreasing. Unfortunately for the argument, the latter assertion is wrong. Hence the former assertion happens to hold, on a restricted $\alpha$-interval, by chance.